# Evidence of atoms from Dulong–Petit law?

Tags: thermodynamics, atoms

All materials have same molar specific heat, cf. the [Dulong–Petit law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulong%E2%80%93Petit_law). Is it an evidence of atoms? What other examples are there for atomic theory?

Comment: [same molar specific heat?](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/tables/sphtt.html)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1566/2451

Comment: you misunderstood me. I wanted to say about [dulong-petit value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulong%E2%80%93Petit_law). Your link was not useful. @Qmechanic

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed: That isn't a valid reason to say that the link wasn't useful! .   (1)    You didn;'t even *specify* that in your question,.   (2)               Still, it shares the same theme, and may be useful to others. ***The aim of SE is not to be useful to the OP only.***  .

Answer (score 1):

The similar molar specific heats show that the materials have the same number of degrees of freedom per mole accessible at room temperature. This is certianly explained by the idea that they are made up of fundamental entities, with the same number of entities per mole, so yes it is evidence for the existance of atoms. I'm not sure I'd call it conclusive evidence on it's own.